# What is the fastest way to solve $a + b = 1$, $a^5 + b^5 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have 2 equations:

$$    a + b = 1\\
    a^5 + b^5 = 1$$

What is the fastest way to solve this system without just guessing the solutions?

Comment: What happens in the first equations if you let $a = 0$ and then $b = 0$ and substitute that into the second equation? We also have $$a^5 + b^5 = (a+b) \left(a^4-a^3 b+a^2 b^2-a b^3+b^4\right) = 1$$

Comment: 'fastest way' is look at it and see that from intuition it's either $a=1,b=0$ or $a=0,b=1$

Comment: @Manx I know I said "fastest solution", but I meant "fastest solution without guessing the answers". My bad on that.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you looking for complex solutions, or just real ones?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Just the real ones, sorry for not clarifying it.

Comment: There should not be anything wrong with "guessing the answers" if you understand that they are rather straightforward _by inspection_ using the experience you have in algebra.

Comment: @AndrewChin I know that, but I want to know how to solve this type of equation system in the future if the numbers are different and I'm not able to guess the solutions right away. In this particular case though, I agree that guessing the answers is the easiest solution.

Comment: In solving systems of equations, the two methods you will typically use are either elimination (by summing scalar multiples of the equations) or substitution (by isolating one variable in one equation and substituting that into the other(s)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-a=b$

Then:

$a^5+(1-a)^5=1$

$a^5-5a+10a^2-10a^3+5a^4-a^5+1=1$

$5a^4-10a^3+10a^2-5a=0$

Factor:

$5a(a-1)(a^2-a+1)=0$

It's clear that the quadratic has no real zeros and the real solutions are $a=0$ and $a=1$. You can find the imaginary zeros by using the quadratic formula on the quadratic factor.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $b=1-a$ into $ a^5 + b^5 = 1$ and factorize,

$$a(a-1)(a^2-a+1)=0$$

which yields the real solution $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.